# In SQL Server how do I tell what values were in a row at a specific date/time?

Tags: sql-server

I have a database that I can view/read data from, but don't have the ability to modify (i.e. can't add triggers or log tables or really do anything to change/modify how it works).

It looks like some data was changed in one of the tables in that database (in fact looks like it was changed multiple times), but there is now no record of those changes or what the historic values are.

My goal: to be able to do something (SQL, logs, fn_dblog, ???) to get the state of a row of a table was on a particular date or to get the list of changes to a table between two particular dates.

I'm hoping from something like

```
SELECT   Table.ColumnOld, Table.ColumnNew
FROM     fn_dblog(NULL, NULL) 
WHERE    Operation = '[delete or update]'
         AND ChangeTime BETWEEN [StartDateTime] and [EndDateTime]
```

Again, unfortunately I don't have the ability to modify or add to the SQL database to auto-log or similar activity, so now I'm just looking for a way of accessing SQL data to know what that row/cloumn looked like at a specific date/time in the past.

Comment: Once that data is changed, unless you have access to the backups/transaction log, the old data is lost.

Comment: I have access to the transaction log (i think that is what the fn_dblog is accessing) ... so i'm just wondering how to access that transaction log to determine what the data was at a specific point in time